# Rotating a Point Around Another Point Gives Unexpected Result

Tags: python, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to rotate a point around another point, but the results are different from what I expect. I'd like to rotate points (0, 1) and (-1, 0) about the origin (0, 0) by 90 degrees. The below code appears to agree with results calculated from this [website](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1223522781), but are the opposite of what I think the outcome should be. If (0, 1) and (-1, 0) are rotated clockwise by 90 degrees about the origin, I expect that the new points will be (1, 0) and (0, 1). The result from the first point is normal, but the result of the second appears to be counter clockwise:
[{'x': 1.0, 'y': 6.123233995736766e-17}, {'x': -6.123233995736766e-17, 'y': -1.0}].

Is there something wrong with my intuition about how the points should rotate? See below for the code:

```
center = {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
vertices = [{'x': 0, 'y': 1}, {'x': -1, 'y': 0}]
angle = 90

def rotate(center, vertices:list, angle):
    # Something appears to be broken with the rotate function
    radians = math.radians(angle)
    cos_angle = math.cos(radians)
    sin_angle = math.sin(radians)

    for vertice in vertices:
        temp_x = (cos_angle * (vertice['x'] - center['x'])) + (sin_angle * (vertice['y'] - center['y'])) + center['x']
        temp_y = (cos_angle * (vertice['y'] - center['y'])) + (sin_angle * (vertice['x'] - center['x'])) + center['y']
        vertice['x'], vertice['y'] = temp_x, temp_y

    return vertices
```

Comment: Is your y-axis pointing up or down?

Comment: Also, complex numbers might be easier to use than trigonometry. Python has those built in.

Comment: Your formula is wrong in the `temp_y` line, it should be `- sin_angle*(vert....)`, check the formula

Comment: @MohilPatel I double checked the formulas, looks like the temp_x line was incorrect with your recommended correction. Thank you! 

Edit: Please write your comment as an answer so that I can select this as resolved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Correction in the formula

```
import math

def rotate(center, vertices:list, angle):
  radians = math.radians(angle)
  cos_angle = math.cos(radians)
  sin_angle = math.sin(radians)

  for vertice in vertices:
      temp_x = (cos_angle * (vertice['x'] - center['x'])) + (sin_angle * (vertice['y'] - center['y'])) + center['x']
      temp_y = (cos_angle * (vertice['y'] - center['y'])) + -1*(sin_angle * (vertice['x'] - center['x'])) + center['y']
      vertice['x'], vertice['y'] = temp_x, temp_y

  return vertices

center = {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
vertices = [{'x': 5, 'y': 4}]
angle = 30

print(rotate(center, vertices, angle))
```

Output

```
>>> [{'x': 1.0, 'y': 6.123233995736766e-17}, {'x': -6.123233995736766e-17, 'y': 1.0}]
```